# Why am I getting: can't locate node [rosout] in package [rosout]

Tags: ros, rosout, rostest, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a rostest from catkin which was added with `add_rostest()`

It runs fine when started with a rostest call directly.

But when I try to run it from catkin I get ...

```
ERROR: failed to start core service [/rosout]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 327, in run
    testMethod()   File "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/rostest/src/rostest/runner.py", line 121, in fn
    succeeded, failed = self.test_parent.launch()   File "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/rostest/src/rostest/rostest_parent.py", line 81, in launch
    return self.runner.launch()   File "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/launch.py", line 644, in launch
    self._setup()   File "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/launch.py", line 621, in _setup
    self._launch_core_nodes()   File "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/launch.py", line 500, in _launch_core_nodes
    raise RLException("failed to start core service [%s]"%node_name)
```

And the log contains ...

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-06-27 13:39:02,666: ... preparing to launch node of type [rosout/rosout]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-06-27 13:39:02,666: create_node_process: package[rosout] type[rosout] machine[Machine(name[] env_loader[None] address[localhost] ssh_port[22] user[None] assignable[True] timeout[10.0])] master_uri[http://cob-stud-5:22422/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-06-27 13:39:02,667: process[rosout-1]: env[{'ROS_DISTRO': 'hydro', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'ORBIT_SOCKETDIR': '/tmp/orbit-aub-ch', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'CPATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/hydro/include', 'LOGNAME': 'aub-ch', 'USER': 'aub-ch', 'WORKSPACE': '/home/aub-ch', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/tmp/keyring-kXgmHb', 'HOME': '/home/aub-ch', 'ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src/my_navigation_test/rostest/tools/rosconsole/config/rosconsole.config', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib', 'MAKEFLAGS': 's', 'SSH_AGENT_PID': '17655', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session32', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/aub-ch/.Xauthority', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/cob-stud-5:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/17620,unix/cob-stud-5:/tmp/.ICE-unix/17620', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'TERMINATOR_UUID': 'urn:uuid:48de640c-fa22-4dc5-ab40-9015e574b201', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/aub-ch/.ros/log/rostest-cob-stud-5-3305.log', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'WINDOWID': '50331652', 'EDITOR': 'gedit', 'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID': '18031', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/tmp/keyring-kXgmHb/gpg:0:1', 'BAG_PATH': '/home/aub-ch/bagFiles', 'BAG_BATH': '/home/aub-ch/bagFiles', 'PATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games', 'MAKELEVEL': '4', 'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE': '/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel:/opt/ros/hydro', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/tmp/keyring-kXgmHb/ssh', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '17609', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/build/test_results', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-qw7LKVpfqU,guid=1e429c64037f84d803149de60028e673', '_': '/opt/ros/hydro/bin/catkin_make', 'XDG_SESSION_COOKIE': '0b9bfd3662ca082ebf4c578400000008-1403855639.912213-1471801688', 'CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/build/test_results', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'UBUNTU_MENUPROXY': 'libappmenu.so', 'MFLAGS': '-s', 'OLDPWD': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/build', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/', 'PWD': '/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/build/my_navigation_test/my_navigation_test', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://cob-stud-5:22422/', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'}]
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2014-06-27 13:39:02,836: can't locate node [rosout] in package [rosout]
[rostest][ERROR] 2014-06-27 13:39:02,837: 


ERROR: rosout is not built. Please run 'rosmake rosout'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175202/why-am-i-getting:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Brosout%5D-in-package-%5Brosout%5D/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an issue with my setup. The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` was somehow in the wrong order. (system folders before workspace) (-> https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/455)

But as described in the linked issue, it was due to multiple sourcing of `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1